# SQL Pivot combined with a SUM/Count

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

Stackers,
I've always struggled with understanding PIVOT's when written in SQL syntax...

My data format:

```
CONTID  STCODE
8203    BA
8203    BA
8203    UY
8203    UY
8203    UY
8203    FA
8203    FA
8203    FA
8203    UY
8203    UY
8203    *LC
8203    *LC
8203    *LC
8203    UY
```

The intended output:

```
CONTID   BA    *LC    UY    FA
8203     2     3      6     3
```

My horrible attempt so far... (I don't know what to put in the brackets or SELECT clause.

```
SELECT c.CONTID, [STCODE] AS 'Burglary Alarm', [STCODE] AS 'Late-to-close'
FROM CUSTOMER c LEFT JOIN CLOGS15 h ON c.SERIALNO = h.SERIALNO 
PIVOT
(
SUM(h.STCODE)
FOR h.STCODE 
IN ([BA], [*LC])
) AS pvt
```

Comment: Try `count()` instead of `sum()`.  You can't sum a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT 
CONTID,
[BA] AS 'Burglary Alarm', 
[*LC] AS 'Late-to-close', 
[UY], 
[FA]
FROM 
(
  SELECT c.CONTID, 
  [STCODE]
  FROM CUSTOMER c 
  LEFT JOIN CLOGS15 h ON c.SERIALNO = h.SERIALNO 
  WHERE C.CONTID LIKE '8203' AND h.EVTYPE = 1 
  AND DATEADD(hour,-6,h.EVDATE) 
  BETWEEN '2015-02-23 06:30:00.000' AND '2015-02-24 06:30:00.000'
) SRC
PIVOT
(
  COUNT(SRC.STCODE)
  FOR SRC.STCODE IN ([BA], [*LC], [UY], [FA])
) AS pvt
```

Comment: This gives me error:
Msg 107, Level 15, State 1, Line 11
The column prefix 'h' does not match with a table name or alias name used in the query.
Msg 107, Level 15, State 1, Line 12
The column prefix 'h' does not match with a table name or alias name used in the query.

Comment: Trying to get the column names to be the "BA", "FA", etc. as well. Not sure if I was clear on that.

Comment: Ah, that worked perfect! What is the correct way to add a WHERE clause to this:

WHERE SRC.CONTID LIKE '8203' 
AND h.EVTYPE = 1 
AND DATEADD(hour,-6,h.EVDATE) BETWEEN '2015-02-23 06:30:00.000' AND '2015-02-24 06:30:00.000'

Comment: You can add that where clause inside query that is aliased as SRC

Comment: rs, one more question - there's some records that have a BA that I do not want to count (based on another field not shown). How can I include that in my WHERE clause so it doesn't count records where STCODE is a BA, but is also in AREA 4?